# Min-Width Not Respected in IE9

Tags: internet-explorer-9, css

I have an outer container with min-width in px, and an inner container with max-width and a small amount of padding (both px also).
In IE 9 the page displays correctly initially, but when I zoom in or re-size smaller the outer container seems to refuse to shrink to its min-width, instead remaining at its current width and throwing up a horizontal scrollbar. However, if you refresh the page it seems to work fine after that. Far as I can tell it only does this in IE9. Chrome, FF, Opera, and IE6-8 all work fine. *That's right, IETester even shows the much-hated IE6 rendering it correctly!* FYI I have a doctype of XHTML 1.0 strict and my IE9 appears to be displaying the page in Internet Explorer 9 Standards mode.

Without having to post all my code, does anyone have a suggestion?

Unfortunately nobody appears to have come across this problem from what I can tell. One other tidbit, to make it even weirder (or perhaps it is a clue), IE9 only seems to do this when viewing the page on a server (when uploaded to my site, or using EasyPHP).  Viewed locally it behaves as it should.
Any information would be helpful, even better ways of getting the effect I desire. To clarify, I would like my page to have a min- and max-width, in pixels. If the viewport is bigger than max width, equal margins (a centered page) is desired.  If the viewport is within the min- and max-width range, I would like to have a small amount of the background visible all the way around so the page's left and right edges are more apparent (rather than just budded up to the edge of the browser -- this is where my padding on the inner container comes in). Finally, if the viewport is smaller than the min-width of the page (inner container), I would still like the padding (small edge of padding) along with a horizontal scrollbar. Any help is greatly appreciated, and let me know if you require more information (if somehow I did not provide enough in my long tirade).

Additional Info: As I said, I'm not keen on going through my whole site's code and picking out the relevant material, but I've gone ahead and wrote up a concise example since someone voted down my question (which wasn't cool btw, but karma will get that dude).

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>IE9 Min-Width Problem</title>
</head>
<body style=" width:100%; height:100%; margin:0; border:0; padding:0;">
<div style=" position:relative; min-width:500px; max-width:100%; margin:auto; background:red; ">
<div style=" position:relative; min-width:0; max-width:1000px; margin:auto; padding:10px; ">
<div style=" position:relative; width:100%; height:500px; background:blue; ">
This is page content
</div><!-- closes content -->
</div><!-- closes inner-wrapper -->
</div><!-- closes outer-wrapper -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: BTW I just remembered a potentially important tidbit: The horizontal scroll bar pops up to make the full width of the outer container visible, but the inner container is the correct width. It is no longer centered in the outer container, but rather it is exactly where it should be (10px from the browser's left edge-the size of my padding). It's just the stupid outer container that won't re-size! Unless of course I refresh the page. Then it never acts up again. What's going on here?! lol

Answer (score 0):

Since you say this only happens when you upload the page, but not locally, are you sure the CSS file is loading properly?  If you 'view source' and follow the link to the CSS, does it load properly?  The CSS file may have not been uploaded or you may be getting some error loading it.

Comment: Yes. All my other styling is working, and the site works as expected in every other browser.

Comment: This appears to be a problem specific to IE9, but it has access to the CSS. My question is, how has nobody encountered this problem?